# Cannot convert an image to gray in opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

Following code is preliminaries before doing some other operations that require a grayscale image.  The problem is my conversion to gray scale does not appear to be working, when do an imshow(test), it's purple and blue-ish.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

red_image = mpimg.imread('/vagrant/notebooks/red_thing.jpg')

import cv2
import numpy as np
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(red_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_red = np.array([30,150,50])
upper_red = np.array([255,255,180])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(red_image,red_image, mask= mask)

# this should be grayscale but when I display it, it contains color:
test = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this.

cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)